# Catalog search returning blank page and no error in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

Finding it hard to debug my problem, I am getting a blank page when searching for a product.

When I check my system.log there's nothing there explaining the error, could someone let me know where I would start debugging this problem!

Sorry if the question is too broad can't think how I would expand it as I can't debug it with no error message to work off!

**EDIT**

Sorry I should of mentioned, yes I have display_errors on and developer debugging and logging etc on.

Comment: Can you turn on the display errors in the index? And developer mode too if possible

Comment: Yes, ensure the logs are enabled. Then I suggest you check the server error log (not Magento logs).

Comment: system.log empty and blank page sounds like memory_limit imho. Can you check your apache error log?

Comment: page is working again now btw.  As simonthesorcerer says, it could be a memory_limit problem or a disk space issue too.

Comment: weird, and yeh logs enabled/ini_dis errors on for deving anyway

Comment: which page is working jon? the whole site works apart from search or did search work for u?

Comment: halp me sander, you seem to always be the one who solves my problems haha :)

Comment: the link you posted works for me as does searching for other things

Comment: ah maybe its a problem with my local cache XD

Comment: derp, guess I should of checked in another browser before posting, didn't think of it because all the other pages were working, I'll accept your answer anyway jon if you mention checking in different browser

Comment: cheers, done that, kind of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly make sure that logging is on in the admin under System>Configuration>Developer, as the other commentators said.

It is a live environment so you could, pro-tem add error reporting to your index.php page, but make sure you remove it once the issue is resolved.  Ideally you could debug the problem on a local environment.

In the [site-root] index.php page you can do the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
```

and possibly

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

(this may be commented out)

Another thing you can do is a add a register_shutdown_function/ e.g.

```
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($error);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

but be warned this will stop the "suppress error" operators (see function calls with @ in the front) so may raise additional problems and should not be run on a live environment. A common surprise issue is the reporting of an error in mage/core/Translate.php .  Another is that Ajax calls may stop working (as errors are added to output, breaking the formatting). So make sure you do not leave this on.

Of course there is the possibility that you are seeing a cached "blank" page in your browser when it is actually working.  Try clearing your cache or forcing a hard reload on the page.  You can achieve this in Chrome by opening your dev tools and right clicking on the refresh button and choosing "clear cache and hard reload", or pressing shift-F5.    Alternatively you can open the page in incognito mode which should ignore the cache.

Comment: Already had all this